# exists formula slowing down query. optimization needed

Tags: mysql, where-clause, exists

```
WHERE   
AND NOT EXISTS
      (SELECT cl.userID
        FROM campaign_list cl
        WHERE cl.userID = customer_profile.userID
        AND (cl.notes = 'report12' or cl.notes = 'report16')
        )
    AND EXISTS
      (SELECT cl.userID
        FROM campaign_list cl
        WHERE cl.userID = customer_profile.userID
        AND cl.notes = 'report11'
        )
    AND
        (SELECT max(cl.send_date)
            FROM campaign_list cl
            WHERE cl.userID = customer_profile.userID
            AND cl.notes = 'report11'
        ) > lastSuccessfulDepositDate
```

without these lines, the query runs in about 20 seconds. However, with the above lines, it takes about 3 minutes to run.

The campaign list is only 3,700 rows, but it's slowly and steadily growing. Any advice for speeding up this query?

Comment: Have you tried the 3 individually? does any one in particular seem to have more of a negative impact?

Comment: How many rows are returned?
How many rows are in the "main table"? (the one not mentioned here that contains lastsuccessfuldepositdate
How many rows are in campaign list?

Comment: I tried all three individually. Not exists = 2:10,  exists = 1:55, max(send_date) = 1:52

Comment: the main table (aka the FROM) is the customer profile table: 143,604 rows. the campaign list is only 3,308 rows.

Comment: The "exists where c.notes='report11'" seems unnecessary given the "max" subquery right below it...

Comment: not really. I need to ask the database guy if I we can create an additional index because right now, I can only do queries and I can't add anything.

Comment: As a developer, I sometimes download some (anonymized) data from production so I can run tests like this on another box and get an idea of what needs to be done before doing it on production.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have the following index:  `campaign_list(userID, notes, send_date)`?  This would be the optimal index for the three subqueries.

Then, I would ask, have you attempted each condition separately?  That is, do you know if each one is taking 1 minute.  Or, is one taking 00:02:59 and the other two 00:00:01 between them?

And, you can simplify the three conditions to these two:

```
WHERE   
AND NOT EXISTS
      (SELECT cl.userID
        FROM campaign_list cl
        WHERE cl.userID = customer_profile.userID AND
              cl.notes IN ('report12', cl.notes = 'report16')
        )
    AND EXISTS
      (SELECT cl.userID
        FROM campaign_list cl
        WHERE cl.userID = customer_profile.userID AND
              cl.notes = 'report11' and
              cl.send_date > ?.lastSuccessfulDepositDate
        )
```

The same index applies here.

Note: The `in` doesn't really affect performance in this case but it is easier to write and to read.

Comment: userid is the primary key. notes and send_date have duplicate values. Hence why I use "max(send_date)"

Comment: may want to use a brin index then-- but the duplicate values are not an issue. Indexes do not have to be and should not be thought of as unique. Just try what I said and post your results... sometimes trial and error beats overthinking things.

Comment: userid is the primary key of what? the index I suggest isn't on customer_profile but on campaign_list-- of course there are duplicate values and an index will help if it's not the primary key of campaign_list

Comment: in the campaign_list table: userid is the primary key. notes and send_date have duplicate values. Hence why I use "max(send_date)"

Comment: I tried all three conditions individually. Not exists = 2:10, exists = 1:55, max(send_date) = 1:52.

Comment: FYI, this is mysql and the brin index seems to be PostgreSQL only

Answer (score 0):

Make sure campiaign_list has an index on userID and notes

You could additionally use a functional index to only index when notes='report16' or 'report11' but that may or may not be good for the system as a whole.

You may also want to include send_date in the same index...

```
create index on campaign_list (notes, user_id, send_date)
```

Also, it's very marginally faster to do select * in your exists query instead of selecting a column name.

Another example:
    create index on campaign_list(send_date) where notes='report11'

Comment: userid is the primary key. notes and send_date have duplicate values. Hence why I use "max(send_date)". If i create an index, is it temporary or permanent? (aka i don't have the capability to add things to my database)

Comment: You might want to use a functional or partial index at least

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the number of rows in each respective table, "IN" and "NOT IN" may give you better results (also depending on your machine's configuration and memory)

example:

```
 where
 customer_profile.userID not in
 (
  (SELECT cl.userID
    FROM campaign_list cl
    WHERE cl.notes not in ('report12','report16')
    [perhaps some other predicate here that's also in the main query]
    )
 )...
```

It'd help to know the number of rows in each table

Comment: the main table (aka the FROM) is the customer profile table: 143,604 rows. the campaign list is only 3,308 rows.

Comment: You might be better off with the "in" and "not in" query I suggested then as it'd only have to go through the campaign_list table one time instead of 143K times-- especially since you don't want to index notes or date...